# Is it possible to run code before Spring Framework controller method is called?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm creating menu and I would like to link my menu items to Spring controller paths. One way to do this is to include menu code to all methods that contain @RequestMapping annotations, but it would be manual task, I would like to automate this task, so that I could just define menu bean and add menu in site template and menus would be generated automatically for every path.

Comment: are you handling menus and links in your view, or somehow adding this in your controller?

Comment: did one of the answers satisfy your question, or are you still looking for suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SpringMVC Interceptors might be a bit easier than the straight AOP above.

- [Spring Reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor)
- [Sample Config](http://www.scottmurphy.info/spring_framework_annotation_based_controller_interceptors)

Note: This approach does couple the code a bit more to Spring MVC, but it'd be an easy port to a similar interception/aspect application in any other framework

Comment: I think the question was clarified - you might also want to look at something like SiteMesh or Tapestry for what you seem to be doing.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have to be a manual task. You can easily add menu code to all methods that contain @RequestMapping annotations by using AOP. Here are the docs 
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html